# How to use remote Mac Mini without local monitor able to see?

Tags: security, mac-mini

I want to use a Mac Mini remotely via the Finder, but my concern is that someone local to the machine could plug in a monitor and see what I was doing.

Is there a way either to:

(1) determine whether a local monitor is plugged in

(2) prevent a local monitor from seeing what a remote user is doing on the machine

Comment: Yes, you can use Apple Remote Desktop to start a screen sharing session so you can access the Mac remotely, but the screen sharing session can be setup so the physical user can't see it.

Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: @AbsterT yes, how would you do that? I heard there was a "curtain" mode or something, but did not see how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to purchase Apple Remote Desktop from the Mac App Store.  Once you have it downloaded and installed you can click on the "Curtain" button and that will allow you to VNC or screen share to the system, but anyone physically there won't be able to see what you are doing.
[image]

Alternatively, you could click the "Control" button and you'll be asked if you want to login to a new screen sharing session where either you Share the screen with someone physically there OR you are logging in as that user, but to a new viewing session only you can see.